# Is there some kind of "weighted maximum" that allows the gradients to backpropagate?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I was wanting to add a maximum in my neural network, but this seems a bad thing to do since it kills the gradients to all but one of the inputs.

Is there some kind of "weighted maximum" that allows the gradients to backpropagate?

Edit: I had a two dimensional tensor (correlation matrix) I wanted to reduce to one dimension.

Comment: "wanting to add a maximum in my neural network", do you mean as an activation function? But how? It's not clear where you would use this "max" function. Edit your post to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum function is not smooth, since it's first derivative is not continuous.

Having non-smooth functions is generally a bad thing for neural networks, since they don't work nicely with gradient decent.

So what you want is a smooth approximation to these functions.

Logsumexp is the smooth approximation to the maximum function and so it is what you should use in a neural network, just like softmax is a smooth approximation to the argmax
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp

Comment: People have been using ReLu functions just fine. Differentiable almost everywhere is probably fine for most applications.

Comment: @StefanPerko `SoftPlus(x) = log(1 + exp(x))` is a smooth approximation to relu which unlike relu would allow the gradients to propagate backwards for x<0, but I doubt there would be any benefit since gradient decent doesn't get stuck with relu anyway, which is interesting